# How to find overlap between groups in Big query SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I have the following Data Set :

```
| user_id | Campaingid| <br>
| 1       | campaign1|  <br>
| 1       | campaign2| <br>
| 2       | campaign1| <br>
| 1       | campaign3| <br>
| 3       | campaign5| <br>
| 3       | campaign2|<br>
| 3       | campaign3|<br>
| 4       | campaign6| <br>
| 5       | campiagn5| <br>
```

I am trying to find the overlap of user_id in campaigns, in other words, how many people in campaign1 were also in campaign2:

I am able to find the distinct users in each campaign by using a group on the campaign id, but I need help with the overlap between different campaigns: The results I am trying to achieve can be demonstrated with a matrix below:

```
Campaign ID| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4| 5| 6| <br>
1 <br>
2 <br>
3 <br>
4 <br>
```

The diagonal gives the people exclusively in campaign1, campaign1-campaign2 is the people who are in campaign1 and also camapaign2.

Is there a way to do it in SQL (Bigquery).
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more simply produced as three columns:

- `campaignid1`
- `campaignid2`
- num users

For this you can use a self-join and aggregation:

```
select d1.campaignid, d2.campaignid, count(*)
from dataset d1 join
     dataset d2
     on d1.userid = d2.userid
group by d1.campaignid, d2.campaignid;
```

You can pivot these results, but that requires knowing the campaigns:

```
select d1.campaignid,
       countif(d2.campaignid = 1) as campaign_1,
       countif(d2.campaignid = 2) as campaign_2,
       countif(d2.campaignid = 3) as campaign_3,
       countif(d2.campaignid = 4) as campaign_4,
       countif(d2.campaignid = 5) as campaign_5
from dataset d1 join
     dataset d2
     on d1.userid = d2.userid
group by d1.campaignid;
```

Comment: I was able to generate the pivot table, I took the count(distinct id) in the first query. After generating the matrix. If I add up the diagonal elements that should be equal to the global count of the distinct ID right? The original distinct user_id count is ~39 million. But when I add the diagonal elements I get ~59 million. Can you help me out as to why this might be the case?

Comment: Multiple users are in one or more campaigns -- you have duplicates.  You can use `count(distinct userid)` if you don't want to investigate this.